# Как создать часы с помощью JavaScript или PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Вида:
2**:**37**:**09 Monday

Comment: Посмотрите вопрос [часы на javascript][1].

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/16459/%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <!------------------------ код -------------------------------->

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var d=document
var NN=d.layers?true:(window.opera&&!d.createComment)?true:false

function showTime(){

 var tmN=new Date()

 var dH=''+tmN.getHours();dH=dH.length<2?'0'+dH:dH

 var dM=''+tmN.getMinutes();dM=dM.length<2?'0'+dM:dM

 var dS=''+tmN.getSeconds();dS=dS.length<2?'0'+dS:dS
 var tmp=dH+':'+dM+':'+dS

 if(NN)d.F.chas.value=tmp;else d.getElementById('tm').innerHTML=tmp

 var t=setTimeout('showTime()',1000)

}
</script>

<div id=tm><form name="F"><input type="button" name="chas" value="XX:XX:XX"></form></div>

<script type="text/javascript">showTime()</script>

<!------------------------ конец кода -------------------------------->
```

[Источник](http://forall.ru-board.com/Svarga/clock_seconds.html).